# Function to calculate increment in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have this code below, to create a function to calculate increment for the employees. Function will take increment percentage and salary as input and return increment amount as output -

```
create or replace function calculate_Increment(incperc number, salary number)
return number
is
begin
insert into employee(emp_id, emp_name, salary, calculate_Increment(10, salary))
values (emp_id, emp_name, salary, v_increment_amount);
end;
/
```

The expected output is -

```
  EMPID      EMPNAME              SALARY     CALCULATE_INCREMENT(10,SALARY)
---------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------------------
       101   Ram                  45000               4500
       102   Sita             54000               5400
       103   Gandhi           35000               3500
       104   Indira           48000               4800
       105   Cholan           25000               2500
```

But I am facing an error -

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
Select empid, empname, salary, calculate_Increment(10, salary) from employee
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function CALCULATE_INCREMENT is in an invalid state
```

Please help me fix this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you do the increment of the salary ? Why do you need the function to insert the rows ? The requirement is not clear.

Comment: Increment of salary is done in function. So just calling the function gives the output? If so how do I call the function?

Comment: where is the function ? could you show me ? if function is there just select it along with other columns as you need ? I wanted to understand before I could answer anything

Comment: The function is "calculate_increment" which is created.

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused completely. what I can tell though your function has errors. 1. You shouldn't use function for insertion purpose. 2. You do not have a return clause 3. You are using variable `v_increment_amount` without declaring it 4. Your current code will result in recursive call without any exit condition which will result in infinite loop...to keep it short if you could tell me step by step what do you really want i could help or else my bad I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function you wrote is invalid for several reasons:

- it doesn't return anything
- you can't perform DML within (OK, you can, if it were an autonomous transaction, but - let's leave that alone)
- `insert` itself doesn't make sense; what is it supposed to be? You can't *insert into a column represented by function*

If I got it correctly, then you should have done it as follows:

```
SQL> create or replace function calculate_increment
  2    (incperc in number,
  3     salary  in number
  4    )
  5  return number
  6  as
  7  begin
  8    return salary * incperc/100;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select emp_id, emp_name, salary, calculate_increment(10, salary) inc
  2  from employee;

    EMP_ID EMP_NAME       SALARY        INC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK            2450        245
      7839 KING             5000        500
      7934 MILLER           1300        130

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table Valued function to increment employee’s salary using employee id by providing percentage of increment. Your function must be able to increment salary of single employee if ID is provided, otherwise in case of no ID is provided, then your function should increment salary for all employees